# Satisfiability in predicate Logic

Tags: logic, computer-science, predicate-logic

I have closed this formula:

$$[\forall x\forall y(P(x,y) \rightarrow P(h(x), h(h(y))))] \rightarrow \forall x(P(x, h(x)) \land P(h(h(x)), x))$$

How could I show that this formula is non-valid but satisfiable? Could I use the [Method of analytic tableux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) here to prove satisfiability? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show satisfiability you need to come up with an interpretation of the $P$ predicate and the $h$ function that will make the statement true.

And to show it is not valid, you need to come up with an interpretation that will make it false.

And yes, you can use a tableaux for this: if you leave the statement as is, and get to an open and finished branch, then that shows the statements is satisfiable. And if you create a tableaux for the negation of the statement and get an open and finished branch, then that shows it is not valid.

Unfortunately, it is possible that you get an infinite tableaux, in which case you do not get an open and finished branch. So, I would suggest just trying some things, and coming up with a concrete interpretation. Taking the domain of natural numbers is always a good start, so that for $P$ you can try things like > or < and for the $h$ function you can try successor or square.

Comment: Thanks Bram. Could you show me an example of using the domain of natural numbers for an interpretation of $P$? Is this like choosing a domain $D = {0,1}$ and choosing an interpretation like *"x is smaller than y"*? I am just unsure of how I should show this?

Comment: @RoadRunner Sure, you could just use $D=0,1$, interpret $P(x,y)$ as $x < y $, and for $h$ you could pick any function, for example $h(0)=1$, and $h(1)=0$.  So, if you do this, what will be the truth-value of the sentence? Well, with this interpretation the first half of the sentence basically says that whenever $x < y$, then $h(x)<h(h(y))$. Well, only have $x<y$ for $0<1$, so let's see if $h(0)<h(h(1))$ ... no, because $h(0) =1$ and $h(h(1))=1$, and $1 \not < 1$. So, the first half of the sentence is false ... but since that is the antecedent of a conditional, the whole sentence is true.

Comment: @RoadRunner OK, so now you want to change things so that the whole sentence becomes false .... which means that the first half should become true, and the second half false ... just start playing around ... maybe just stick to those two objects $0$ and $1$, but change the $h$ function of the $P$ predicate. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I understand now. Thank you for providing a very in depth answer :)